# When body is 100% and elements go into height more than 100%, background gets cut

Tags: css

So I have `html` and `body` elements CSS set to `height: 100%` and when my elements on page take more than 100% of the screen height, as expected scroll bar appears which allows me to scroll down to see elements that reached limit of 100%, however in such case background gets cut down. Code I mentoined:

**Edit:** Problem still appears even if I remove `height: 100%` rules from both elements.

```
html
  //height: 100%
  body
    //height: 100%
```

Here are screenshots:

[image]
[image]

How do I fix this? I want my background to be on whole page not just first 100% of the page.

**Edit:**
Here is almost all of my CSS from this page:

```
.animated-gradient
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #a3f51b, #057fd2, #d205b8)
  background-size: 600% 600%
  -webkit-animation: animated-gradient 30s ease infinite
  -moz-animation: animated-gradient 30s ease infinite
  animation: animated-gradient 50s ease infinite

*
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  box-sizing: border-box

html
  min-height: 100%
  body
    min-height: 100%
    font-size: 17px
    background-attachment: fixed

#main-menu
  position: relative

.main-menu-item
  cursor: pointer
  +bs1()
  background: $white
  transition: all .25s
  //&:hover
    +scale(1.05, 1.05)
  &:active
    +scale(0.95,0.95)
  i, span
    display: block

.box-size-11
  width: 9.5vw
  height: 9.5vw
  margin: .25vw
  float: left
  vertical-align: top
  i, span
    font-size: 5vw
    text-align: center
  span
    font-size: 1vw

.box-size-21
  @extend .box-size-11
  width: 9.5vw * 2 + 0.5vw
```

HTML structure

```
<body> <!-- body is the element with background and its one that gets cut down -->
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does changing `height` to `min-height` fix it?

Comment: @Garconis nope. even if I remove both properties problem appears. I remember having similar problem on one website I was building long time ago but I can't remember how I solved it.

Comment: Delete line 77 of your CSS and you're good to go!

Comment: @Rob Is that supposed to be a joke? Sarcasm because I didn't give enough CSS info? If so, I'll provide more code.

Comment: You didn't supply any CSS or HTML so I thought my guess was as good as anyone elses.

Comment: Still need the HTML but I don't do CSS pre-processors so I don't want to interpret all that. Your images are unnecessary except a small part to visualize the problem. Screenshots of dev tools are useless and you need to simplify to where the problem is and describe which parts affect your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using fixed positioning on the background.
By default, backgrounds such as the one you used (as opposed to repeating/solid which negate the issue) will be positioned absolute. So the height scales to 100% but the background remains at the same position.

This can be done by adding the following at the end of your css object:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

EDIT:

Create an additional div to house the gradient. Using BODY restricts usage of fixed positioning. So, in your case, you can simply move .animated-gradient to its own div with no children, and use fixed positioning.

Comment: I added this rule to body element (the one with the background) and it didn't work for me. I also added it to class that has the background and same result.

Comment: Did you add it to .animated-gradient AFTER the background properties?

Comment: I looked around and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094134/fixed-gradient-background-with-css Same problem and solution. You must be inheriting something that's preventing the code from working. Should be able to see this in the inspector.

Comment: That is not same problem. In my case, the element gets cut down (check screenshot 2), not the background itself.

Comment: Try using a separate class from BODY. So: 

html body gradient /gradient /body /html

As opposed to styling the body element.

Comment: Do you mean adding another child div to body that is parent to all other divs that were inside body?

Comment: Add a child div that is not parent to any additional elements. That way you can use fixed positioning without affecting the rest of the body.

Comment: I added one div that is inside body but not related to any other element and has `position: fixed` and `height: 100%` and it works well now, please update the answer with this info, so I can accept your answer as correct

Comment: Great to hear, I added a quick edit with the solution.

Comment: i Love U, u make my day, thanks for that!!!! it's works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will result in exactly what you want be Here is what I got to work. Create a container (I used a DIV) at the top of your page (I put mine directly after the body tag), an empty container... the code I am pasting below has inline styles applied to it, but you can pull the styles out and put them in your CSS if you would like.

```
<div style="
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #a3f51b, #057fd2, #d205b8);
  animation: animated-gradient 50s ease infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:fixed;">
</div>
```

absolute positioning works as expected, but the background does not scroll with the user, so we add position fixed, to make the background follow the user as they scroll through the web page.  You might have to add a Z-index and fool around with numbers to make sure your new background does not cover any of your content... I added a z-index:-10 to put it behind my content... Enjoy! :)

Comment: Yeah this fixes the problem but you are just few minutes too late, this same solution was mentioned in answer above.

Comment: Ahhh darn! Oh well, all that matters is that your problem is resolved! :)