# I can not use position fixed and linear gradient at the same time. why is it?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I don't know a lot about coding and this is actually a school assignment. I want to use `position:fixed` while my background is gradient but when I use `position:fixed` my background gradient disappears.

```css
body{
      height: 92vh;
      margin-top: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      /*position: fixed; Probem when added*/
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(204, 63, 142), rgb(9, 78, 195));
    }
```

I guess it has a problem with background-image

Comment: The `<body>` shouldn't need to be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Can this solve your problem: instead of `position: fixed;` try `background-attachment: fixed;`

```css
body{
  height: 92vh;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(204, 63, 142), rgb(9, 78, 195));
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

And yes see @david-ngumbu answer to have a better specification for the linear gradient ;)

source: [Fixed gradient background with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094134/fixed-gradient-background-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add to @zerbene's answer You also have to specity the direction of the linear gradient for example `linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(204, 63, 142), rgb(9, 78, 195))` will set the gradients direction from top then to bottom example 2: `linear-gradient(to right, rgb(204, 63, 142), rgb(9, 78, 195))` it will set the `linear-gradient` from left to right. You can also add degrees to you linear gradients like this `linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(204, 63, 142), rgb(9, 78, 195))`.

Comment: It defaults to `to bottom`.

Comment: It's still recommended to add `to bottom` to the linear gradient even though it is the default value.