# CSS How do I fit a background to the entire length of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My page is long and requires the user to scroll to view the entire thing. I want the background (it's a CSS3 gradient) to stretch throughout the entire length of the page, even if the user resizes the window. I am using a bit of code from another thread that does this. However once I switch the page to fullscreen the background is cut off at the bottom. The code I am using is below.

```
function adjustBackground() {
    var pageHeight = $('html').height();
    var body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;

    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                           html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    document.getElementById("page-top").style.backgroundSize = "100% " + height + "px";
}
/* 
  page-top is the ID of the body. 
  The code gets the height of the page and should 
  set the height of the page to the height.
*/

$(document).ready(function(){
   adjustBackground();
});

body.onresize=function(){
    adjustBackground();
};
```

Comment: if the background is a CSS gradient, you shouldn't have to set any size for it - it should fill the whole container by default (?)

Comment: why use an id for the body if you've the reference to it already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making gradient background fill page with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841323/making-gradient-background-fill-page-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the min-height of both the body and html elements to 100%. What happens is the body doesn't actually extend all the way to the bottom of the viewport, so the background doesn't extend down there either (only 100% of the height of the body or html tag (if you set the background w/CSS).

You should be able to do this without any JavaScript (nicer for you to work with).
Example:

```
body, html {
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #ccc; /* Replace "#ccc" with your css gradient */
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

You can use an online tool such as http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to generate the CSS you want for the gradient, if you want something visual.

Comment: Example JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qtdgem42/ Remove the min-height: 100% on the html, body tags to see how crucial that is.

Comment: And, on second look, it appears you only need to set that on the html element. Perhaps non-Chrome browsers need it on both... I forget. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting the body to span the whole page with the desired background using `vw`(*hundredths of the viewport width*) and `vh`(*hundredths of the viewport height*) from `CSS3`

```
body {
    background: #ccc; /* Replace "#ccc" with your css gradient */
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```