# linear gradient in html not covering entire page

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML page. I want to make background of the page gradient. I have written following code but instead of creating a single gradient from black to white running from top of the page to the bottom of the page, the browser (chrome) is creating multiple small repeating patterns of the gradient. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:font-variant="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML Test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body{
        background-color:#000000;
        background-image:linear-gradient(#000000,#ffffff);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just found that the answer has been provided here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841323/making-gradient-background-fill-page-with-css

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```css
body, html {
height: 100% !important;
}
```

This will span the body across the whole viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

need to specified body height or need some dummy content. then your code work fine.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body{
    background-color:#000000;
    background-image:linear-gradient(#000000,#ffffff);
    height:700px;
    }
</style>
```